# img height and max-width issue with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, image-size

On this [page](http://betaeascongress.pemsea.org/videos), the columns for the video thumbnails don't seem to display consistently (equally) on Chrome. On IE and FF, both column widths are equally displayed.

My global CSS for image have been set to:

```
img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Altering any values will affect other image rendering. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Removing `max-width` globally fixes it, or override it with `min-width` instead. max-width only sets the maximum width permitted, not an actual width

```
.cboxElement img {
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you don't actually set a width, meaning browsers and images can render any way they want, giving unpredictable results as you've seen.

The easiest solution is to just size your columns to a fixed 50% width, like so:

```
.page-videos .view-video td {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Leave the `max-width: 100%` in place, it will ensure that even large images fit this 50% perfectly.

Feel free to replace the classes of my sample code, they are simply a best guess at ensuring we only change this one table, but you may know better/more-specific classes for this project.